# android studio java_home is not defined correctly

Tags: android, linux, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I had imported a project from eclipse to android studio. I followed the instructions how to export by generating a gradle from eclipse. As expected, things didn't go smoothly when importing it into android studio. I have encountered this error in my gradle.

```
Error : (1,0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
```

Then I entered this command in the terminal: `ant -debug`. I found that JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. I found out it was about gradle. I checked my gradle with gradle -v but gradle was not available. I solved it by creating a symbolic link and solved the problem.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Monday, September 9, 2013 8:44:25 PM UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on April 8 2014
Ivy: non official version
JVM: 1.7.0_67 (Oracle Corporation 24.65-b04)
OS: Linux 3.13.0-36-generic amd64
```

So, I tried `ant -debug again` and got this error:

```
JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
We cannot execute /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_45/bin/java
```

`echo $JAVA_HOME` gave me this `/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_45`

I checked my `/etc/environment` with the following result:
`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

How do I solve this? I tried many solutions, none of them worked. I already spent a day working this out. Any advice would be appreciated. If you need additional info, just tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved. I tried a different approach in migrating my project to the android studio.

**I did not follow the steps in the android developer's site**.

**I imported it without generating **gradle** from eclipse**.

I made a copy of my project from eclipse and imported it using the import project in android studio it automatically generated its own gradle and included the libraries I used in eclipse. It took a while but it worked.